# Why do the tangential intersection correspond to max/min of function in Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Lagrange multipliers are used to find max/min of function $f(x,y)$ given a constraint $g(x,y)=c$. They do so by assuming the max/min occurs where there are a tangential intersection.

Consider this example: $f(x,y)$ is two planes intersecting at a line forming a V shaped wedge extending upwards to infinity. $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the unit circle. Clearly the min occurs at the line where the two planes intersect. However, this line is not tangential to the unit circle, it goes right down the middle of it.

According to this example, the assumption that both the max/min occur at a tangent is wrong. Can someone explain?

Comment: Well your example isn't differentiable in every direction, so it is a bad example. Even if you smoothed this planar intersection to a smooth valley, the minimum would still occur at a tangential intersection, because $f$ has gradient $(0,0)$ at the bottom of the valley, it is trivially tangent to the gradient of $g$ because $(0,0)$ is in the span of any vector.

Comment: @whpowell96 could you please elaborate. you said "it is trivially tangent to the gradient of " I think the equation 2+2-1 = 0 has many tangents not only one as it is a circle. Moreover (0,0) is not part of this circle and as it is not part of this circle how can it be the minimum of the function and satisfying the constraint?